# "Unexpected PROPERTYELEMENT in parse rule Element" C# Error

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, windows-phone

[image]

Hello! I am trying to translate my Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) app into multiple lanugaes and when I add:

```
<Application.Resources xmlns:my="clr-namespace:HowtoWP8Http"> //"HowtoWP8Http" is a namespace
    <my:LocalizedStrings x:Key="Localized"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

into app.xaml i end up with this cryptic error, i have no idea how to solve it, my forms are loading strings from translated files just fine but when I actually try to compile the project it ends up like this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved myslef by the pure luck, if anyone have similar problem ::
[image: solved]

Comment: This is because `Application.Resources` is actually a property, not an object. You can't have attributes on properties.